# File cannot be opened, version is too old

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit

I want to load a particle system into my ARKit app, but I get this error when I try to do this:

```
[SceneKit] Error: This file cannot be opened (version is too old)
```

I am loading the particles with this code (in a `SCNNode` subclass):

```
init() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Models.scnassets/particles/particles", withExtension: "scnp")
        else { fatalError("can't find expected virtual object bundle resources") }
    guard let node = SCNReferenceNode(url: url)
        else { fatalError("can't find expected virtual object bundle resources") }
    super.init()
    self.addChildNode(node)
}
```

I have this code from the ARKit demo app (from Apple). The `particles.scnp` is generated from the Xcode template `Bokeh`. I have Xcode 9 beta 4 and my device runs iOS 11 beta 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SCNReferenceNode` can only reference scene files. Examples of scene file extensions are `dae` and `scn`.

A `.scnp` file is an archive of a `SCNParticleSystem`, and so it can't be used.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I fixed it by moving the particle system into a `.scn` file